# HTTP or Websocket for a low-latency web game?

Tags: javascript, http, tcp, websocket

I am new to web development and I just want to know some performance comparison.

I am building a tetris battle game on the web. Most of the game logics are inside of a server, which is built in C++. For clients, I am planning to use cocos2d-js, which is basically javascript.

Players' behavior will affect opponents. First, users' inputs need to get to the server correctly, the server applies inputs to the logic, and it will send a new game state back to clients. Client only needs to represent sprites on the screen.

My original plan was to implement it with TCP socket since it may need low latency. However, I just realized that we don't use TCP socket on the web.

Is it feasible to use HTTP connection for this kind of application?
Should I try web socket?
What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can certainly use HTTP for this but for real-time communication the best option is using websockets.

Raw Sockets (aka, TCP sockets) **are not part of the W3C standard**.
Even though some browsers have [implemented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TCPSocket) them, I'd recommend avoiding using them unless you don't care about locking your application with that specific browser.

In general, using Websockets will be your best option, they offer the same performance as raw sockets and are easier to use from JS.
Unfortunately, using a C++ server might be more complicated for this, since your server must implement the protocol, you can find some implementations on the internet like [this](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) one, for example.

Or, if you want to have a simpler integration with client/server you could try out Node.js to implement your server logic and use the [Socket.io](http://socket.io) library to handle communication, which will also handle incompatible browsers gracefully. Note that Socket.io **uses a different [protocol](https://github.com/automattic/socket.io-protocol)**, so I don't recommend trying to use it with your current C++ server if you want to avoid doing lots of extra work.

To sum things up

#### Raw (TCP) Sockets

- **Pros:** easier to integrate with your current C++ server
- **Cons:** browser support isn't guaranteed, not a (web) standard, will need more work for synchronization, communication, etc.

#### Websockets

- **Pros:** performance on par with TCP sockets, easier to implement client-side
- **Cons:** you might have to do more work on your server implementation

My personal recommendation would be avoiding TCP sockets if possible and stick to the standards.

**Edit:** Apparently, TCP sockets [might](http://www.w3.org/TR/tcp-udp-sockets/) end up being a W3C standard, the APIs are still a draft (and a pretty recent one), so I still recommend against using them (latest Chrome has an experimental implementation).

Comment: With Raw TCP sockets you still have to put a framing mechanisim in place, that is basically what the WS protocol is.

Answer (score 0):

I think @Sosdoc has given the correct answer. The only thing i want to add that a libarary like SignalR can help you very much with the implementaton of websockets. You might want to check out the c++ signalr-qt project on github: https://github.com/p3root/signalr-qt

Comment: SignalR is a polyfill, with many scalability problems that are explained in its documentation about "scaling out". I would use raw WebSockets.